# Spring SSO always creates new session after refresh the client web app

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I was creating my own oauth2 server with SSO enabled for Google and Facebook. I found this example https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2 to be very useful and I was able to make my oauth2 server expandable after several tweaks.

For session storage, I used redis and everything seems to be working with the spring magics.

However I encountered a session problem when implementing logout. According to single sign on best practice, when a user logout from one client, all other clients with the same session from the auth server should also be logged out. So I added an endpoint for each client to invoke upon successful login to register it's name based on the user session from the auth server. However I noticed that each time I refresh the page on my client web app, I get a new session from the auth server. As a result, each time when I try to logout, the session associated with all registered clients will always become the old one.

I've been searching for solutions online but no luck yet. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me with this issue.

**TL;DR version:**

I implemented an oauth2 server with SSO enabled for Facebook with Spring Boot. After I successfully logged in with my Facebook account, I can see my client web app resources. Every time I refresh the page, I see a new session gets created from the oauth2 server and it gets stored in the redis storage and all the old sessions are kept in the storage as well.

**UPDATE**

It seems that all the new sessions are generated by anonymous users each time I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some digging, it turns out that anonymous user by Spring Boot is not much different from unauthenticated users, according to this doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/anonymous.html.

It makes sense that every time I refresh page a new session would generate. My problem was that I wasn't using the correct session ID when registering client app upon successful user authentication. Therefore I override "SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java" file so that I can obtain client_id from the request parameter and then register the correct session ID obtained from the Authentication object to this client ID.